# git fails to clone: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, bash, ssh, bitbucket

I'm using [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) for my team project.
The problem only appeared after I deleted the local repository (because it wouldn't let me commit changes, but that's another story).
But when i cloned for the first time, it did work (I used the HTTP URL).

Currently, when I try to clone using the Visual Studio's team explorer GUI (team explorer tab: connect -> Local Git Repositories -> Clone, and entering the HTTP URL of the git repository, the following message appears:

> Failed to clone the remote repository. See the Output window for more
>   details.

The Output window says:

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

---

If I enter the SSH URL instead (using the same method again) it pops:

> Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.

---

If I use git bash and enter `git clone <HTTP URL>` it prints:

> error: RPC failed; curl 52 Empty reply from server
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

---

If I use git bash and enter `git clone <SSH URL>` it prints:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more information, it looks like you are not authenticated. 
follow the instruction on the bitbucket wiki here and see if that solves the problem

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/permission-denied-publickey-302811860.html

Be sure to use the correct url for the corresponding access scheme too.

good luck.

Comment: But a few weeks ago I did use the HTTP URL, there was no need to use SSH URL. There's no other way? What information can I supply that can help clarify my situation?